# Optimising usage of a frequently repopulated std::list<Class*> object in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, optimization, stdlist

OK, this is going to be a rather long question, because the issue might relate to the broader structure/organization of my code, rather than a specific line. Thanks in advance for those willing to take a look!

**Model structure** I have a computational biological model written in C++ which consists of multiple classes written in separate header and source files. I will try to simplify the problem as much as possible. Relevant here is that there are biol. cells (class `Cell`; see below if you prefer reading code), which have two compartments, `A` and `B` (i.e. two objects of class `Compartment`), each of which has a genome, `G` (i.e. single object of class `Genome`). Finally, the genome defines two lists of genes (pointers to `Gene` class). `GeneList` simply stores all genes that make up the genome (i.e. the essence of a genome). The second list, `ExpressedGenes`, contains only genes that are expressed, and this is what my question revolves around.

```
//simplification of Cell.hh
class Cell
{
 public:
  Compartment *A, *B;
};

//simplification of Compartment.hh
class Compartment
{
 public:
  Genome *G;
};

//simplification of Genome.hh
class Genome
{
 public:
  std::list<Gene*>* GeneList;
  std::list<Gene*>* ExpressedGenes;
};

//simplification of Gene.cc
class Gene
{
 public:
  //...
  int expression;
};
```

**Model description** To simulate a cell's behaviour, the core of what the model needs to do is calculate which genes become expressed the next timestep (`expression` set to `0` or `1`), based on what genes are expressed during the current timestep. But, gene expression in say compartment A is not only determined by the genes in compartment A's genome, but also by those in compartment B's genome. We imagine that with a small probability the product of an expressed gene can be transported to the other compartment, influencing the subsequent gene expression in that compartment. Again, simplified, the entire update of a cell then appears in the following way.

```
//inside Cell.cc
Cell::UpdateCompartments()
{
   std::list<Gene*>::iterator it;

   A->G->NativeExpression(); //Create ExpressedGenes of A; see below.
   B->G->NativeExpression(); //Create ExpressedGenes of B.

   Transport(); //Potential movement (by splicing) of elements in ExpressedGenes of A to ExpressedGenes of B, and vice versa.

   A->G->UpdateGeneExpression(); //Use ExpressedGenes of A to update expression for each gene in GeneList of A.
   it = A->G->ExpressedGenes->erase(A->G->ExpressedGenes->begin(), A->G->ExpressedGenes->end()); //Erase ExpressedGenes of A, gene expression has been stored in the gene objects.

   B->UpdateGeneExpression(); //Same but for B.
   it = B->G->ExpressedGenes->erase(B->G->ExpressedGenes->begin(), B->G->ExpressedGenes->end());
}

//inside Genome.cc
void Genome::NativeExpression()
{
    std::list<Gene*>::iterator it;

    //Iterate through GeneList, if we find a gene that is expressed, store a pointer to it in ExpressedGenes.
    it = GeneList->begin();
    while (it != GeneList->end())
    {
        if ((*it)->kind==REGULATOR || (*it)->kind==EFFECTOR)
        {
            Gene* gene = dynamic_cast<Gene*>(*it);
            if(gene->expression > 0)    ExpressedGenes->push_back(gene);
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

**Problem statement** The problem is that the boring little piece of code above (i.e. the function `NativeExpression`) costs more time than anything else in the model (see results from GPROF analysis below). This seems weird to me because, `ExpressedGenes` being a list of pointers should not be so much overhead right? And I am just creating pointers to *existing* Gene objects, and removing them later... As shown by the GPROF output, time is largely wasted during the function itself (220.01s), not by any of the calls within it (i.e. iterating through the list, checking elements, adding new elements; total of 28.92s). Furthermore, I found no difference in the time profile when I replaced the `dynamic_cast` with a `static_cast`. These points lead me to believe that the inefficiency might be in the broader structure of my classes, or in how I use pointers between them. So, suggestions or other remarks will be much appreciated.

[image]
...
[image]

Comment: The first step of optimising an `sd::list` should *usually* be replacing it with `std::vector` or `std::deque`.

Comment: If each cell has its own compartments why do you store them as pointers? Couldn't they be part of each cell object?

Comment: While I don't specifically doubt the conclusion (that most time is spent in `NativeExpression` itself .. by iterating through the `std::list` I guess?), `gprof` is not very accurate at all, and you should probably try `perf`. The results would help us answer the question too .. but yea it's probably the `std::list`.